# Showing values from a JSON file according to their value of a key

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json file that every object has 3 keys and values. Description, poster image and genre. Each object is for movies. I succeeded to append poster images and descriptions. But now I want to hide them all and then show the ones that has particular "genre" values when I click a link. I did the hiding stuff. When I click "drama" link, jquery hides all movie posters and descriptions. I want to add the code that can show again the ones with particular "genre" values to it. How can I do it? The code I wrote so far is below. First "drama" is id of the link, second is the value of "genre" key. Each "Box" includes a movies poster and description.

```js
        $("#drama").click(function() {

          $(".box").hide();

          if (data.movies.genre === "drama") {
            $(".box").show();
          };

        });
```

Comment: match to a class on the elements. An element can have multiple classes. Something like `$(".box."+data.movies.genre).show();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use data attributes to do this.  So, when you're building the elements, add data-genre attribute.  JQuery can select on these attributes and you can hide/show a group of them pretty easily.

Also, to improve quality, you could use the same mechanism on the button/link to show/hide a genre.

In html:

```
<div class="box" data-genre="drama">DRAMA BOX</div>
<div class="box" data-genre="comedy">COMEDY BOX</div>
<div class="box" data-genre="drama">DRAMA BOX 2</div>
<div class="box" data-genre="romance">DRAMA BOX 2</div>

<button class="filter-button" data-genre="drama">Drama</button>
<button class="filter-button" data-genre="comedy">Comedy</button>
```

In js:

```
$(".filter-button").click(function() {
    $(".box").hide();
    $(".box[data-genre=" + $(this).data('genre') + "]").show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ukf3dzy2/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could name each genre box element with its own id and then use a generic method to handle the change.

```
function showHide(element) {
   if(element.id == "drama") {
       $("#dramabox").show();
       $("#actionbox").hide();
   } elseif (element.id == "action") {
       $("#actionbox").show();
       $("#dramabox").hide();
   }

}
```

then use it in click event call

```
$("#drama").click(function() {
    showHide(this);
});

$("#action").click(function() {
    showHide(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class for genre on the elements. Elements can have multiple classes

```
<div class="box drama">
```

Then filter that class to show

```
$("#drama").click(function() {
    $(".box").hide().filter('.'+data.movies.genre).show();  
});
```